# What would be VSI indications of an aircraft sideslipping to a blocked static vent while descending?

Tags: flight-instruments, vertical-speed

The aircraft has two static vents, each on left and right side of fuselage. Left static port is blocked and aircraft is sideslipping to left at an INCREASING rate while descending. Would VSI overread or underread?

Comment: Why do you think a static port would be "blocked"? It's a static port, it doesn't care about the attitude of the aircraft.

Comment: @JuanJimenez a static port can be blocked any time and there have been cases, due to dust etc

Comment: You are not talking about a static port being blocked by foreign matter, you are talking about sideslipping. No static port can be blocked due to sideslipping.

Comment: I'm talking about a case where a port is blocked and an aircraft is sideslipping. I've never said the port is blocked due to sideslipping.

Comment: The answer is still the same, if there are two static ports and one is blocked the other one still won't care if the aircraft is side slipping and neither will the VSI. I suggest you edit your question to properly state what you are asking.